# showing html table tag name by mouse click or hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written an html code which show a table. Now what i want to do is like  that, clicking or hovering mouse  over the table then the tag name will show. As i am new in jquery i am unable to organize the logic in  jquery.
The following html code generate a simple table

```
 <div class="css">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>User</th>
                            <th>Country</th>
                            <th>City</th>
                            <th>BithDate</th>

                        </tr>

                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>abc</td>
                            <td>abc</td>
                            <td>abc</td>
                            <td>abc</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>cdf</td>
                            <td>cdf</td>
                            <td>cdf</td>
                            <td>cdf</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>
```

the out put
[image]

Now what i want to do is like that when i click on user/country it will show: "thead: th" and when i point mouse on abc or cdf it will show:  "tr: td".

what i thought to do is using click event for each tr td . but is there any other way to do that. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Wouldn’t it be simpler to use existing developer tools in browsers? Information like element nesting is something that is hardly of interest to end users, and developers should know how to use the dev tools in a few browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Try following,

```
$('table').click(function(event){
    // The event.target property returns which DOM element triggered the event.
    // 
    var elem = event.target.nodeName;
    // use this value to display in your way.
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/go4vaibhav/9hnkd55g/2/)

Comment: Could you please add a working example in  JSFiddle because i cant make it workable. i alert elem variable  but  its not working @Vaibhav Katole

Comment: I have attached a demo, please check. @MAT14

Comment: Thanks it works now i forgot to add it on-load function

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var $display = $('<div>TEST</div>');

$display
    .css({
        position: 'absolute',
        background: '#fff',
        border: '1px solid #000',
        padding: '2px 8px'
    })
    .appendTo('body');

$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    var offset = $display.width() / 2;

    $display.css({
        top: e.pageY + 20,
        left: e.pageX - offset
    });
});

$('*').not($display).mouseenter(function(e){
    var tags = $(this).parents().map(function(){
        return this.tagName;
    }).get().reverse().join(': ');

    $display.html(tags);
});
```